# Is there a method in cocoa to convert the keycode to an ascii character?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I see the technique to convert ASCII character to a keycode.  But see nothing on converting the keycode returned by the listener back to an ascii character.

Comment: When you say keycode, do you mean a virtual key code, like the result of the `keyCode` method of `NSEvent`?  Or do you mean a numerical character value, or what?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question correctly, this should work.

```
NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString string];
int value = 0;
sscanf([strkeyCodeValueHere cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
[newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
```

Comment: wow - thanks a lot, this had me going nuts trying to find anything on the network that would lead me in the right direction.  I would love to bump you up, but I'm new to this forum and don't have any points yet.

Comment: Normally after a certain time, you could accept it's answer.

Comment: Keep in mind you're converting a virtual key code to ASCII but that not all key boards or input methods are actually going to correspond to this. Not all keyboards are US.